# React Native ScrollView single child not scrolling without height

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on an app, where I have a screen, whose content is larger than the size of my screen (the height of the content depends on data from API). So I wrapped the content in a View and put this View inside ScrollView to make the screen scrollable. However it will not scroll, unless I specify the height of the content in contentContainerStyle.

To understand how it works, I put a single Text component with a long text and large font size (so that it exceeds my screen size) inside a ScrollView, and it is just normal scrollable even without setting contentContainerStyle. Could somebody explain, how does it work, and why my content is not scrollable in the first case?

Current working code:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: contentHeight}}>
        {renderContent()}
        {/* <Text style={{fontSize: 300}}>AABABBABABABABABBAB</Text> */}                    
    </ScrollView>  
</View>
```

Comment: did you give flex:1 to the scrollview style prop?

Comment: sure, still did not work...